# How to send only one Byte over a Bluetooth Socket (RFCOMM, SPP) or How to flush a Bluetooth Socket (RFCOMM, SPP)?

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have set up a connection between my PC and a Bluetooth device using a MS Bluetooth socket based on RFCOMM and Serial Port Profile (SPP).

There is no problem to receive data continuously. However, if want to send one byte (which acts as a command), the device does not receive it.

Here are the code snippets (error handling omitted):

```
SOCKET s = ::socket (AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM); //successful
...
SOCKADDR_BTH btSockAddr;
ZeroMemory(&btSockAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));

btSockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
btSockAddr.btAddr = DEVICE_ADDRESS;
btSockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID; //SerialPortServiceClass_UUID
btSockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
...
err = ::connect(s, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&btSockAddr), sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH)); //successful

char cmd = 'm'; //switch mode
int sentSize = ::send(s, &cmd, 1, 0); //successful, sentSize = 1

...
for(;;)
{
    char out;
    int recvSize = ::recv(s, &out, 1, 0);   //successful, receive byte by byte
    ...
}
```

Though `::send` returns successfully, the device's mode has not changed. So, apparently, the byte given has not been transmitted and still resides in the send buffer (that is my assumption). Is there a way to force sending only one byte, i.e. to send unbuffered?

I can rule out a mistake on device side. Setting up the Bluetooth link manually (Windows Notification Bar / Bluetooth / Add device) und using Putty to establish a serial connection, both receiving and sending are working as expected.

OS: Windows 7
IDE: Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

When you use Putty with the virtual COM port do you hit return after entering your single command character?

I suspect so, and thus you need to send CR+LF after the command byte.  So pass a buffer of size three to send (i.e. { <command>, 0x0D, 0x0A }).  Your device is presumably line based and it waiting for a "line".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, the device is not line based. Once I press a key, its mode is changed immediately, no need to hit return. Would have been a good point, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, try number 2! :-)

This line is probably the problem:

```
btSockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID; //SerialPortServiceClass_UUID
```

Why did you change from SerialPortServiceClass_UUID?  With RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID that tells the RFCOMM socket to connect to *any* service in the SDP (service database) that uses protocol RFCOMM.  You want instead to have:

```
btSockAddr.serviceClassId = SerialPortServiceClass_UUID
```

(Of course that wouldn't actaully cause the problem you are seeing if the device has only one RFCOMM service in the SD).

Comment: Your last remark applies, unfortunately ;-). There is only one service (the SPP) available so replacing the serviceClassID would not change anything.

Comment: By the way, am I right to expect this RFCOMM based socket to send everything unbuffered? I mean, a common TCP/UDP socket buffers and let the underlying layers decide when to actually send.